# Why is my CSS not working on my footer but working for everything else?

Tags: html, css

For some reason the css for the footer portion of my code is not working.  I want the footer to have a green background and for it to be outside the normal container.  The css is working for the other stuff.  Has anyone experienced this before?

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header"></div><!--end header -->

        <div id="content">
            <div class="container">
                <!--================== Navigation ===========================-->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                            <li class="active">
                                <a href="#">Home</a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="#">About</a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Programs</a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Academics</a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Research</a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Alumni</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--======================= Feature =====================-->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
                            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                <li class="active" data-slide-to="0"
                                data-target="#myCarousel"></li>

                                <li data-slide-to="1" data-target=
                                "#myCarousel"></li>

                                <li data-slide-to="2" data-target=
                                "#myCarousel"></li>
                            </ol><!-- Carousel items -->

                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                <div class="active item">
                                    …
                                </div>

                                <div class="item">
                                    …
                                </div>

                                <div class="item">
                                    …
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- Carousel nav -->
                            <a class="carousel-control left" data-slide="prev"
                            href="#myCarousel">‹</a> <a class=
                            "carousel-control right" data-slide="next" href=
                            "#myCarousel">›</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--======================= About =======================-->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <div id="about">


                            <h2>About the DPO</h2>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="dpo-about">
                                <p><br>
                                Since its inception in 1968, the Diversity
                                Programs Office (DPO) has positively impacted
                                the academic, professional and personal growth
                                of tens of thousands of underrepresented
                                minority students through a range of
                                programs.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--=================== Meet the Staff ==================-->

                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div id="staff">


                            <h2>Meet the Staff</h2>
                        </div>
                        <!--=================Thumbnails==================-->

                        <div class="row-fluid">
                            <div class="thumbnails" style="margin-left: 2em">
                                <div class="staff">
                                   <ol>
                                    <div class="staff-image">

                                            <li>
                                                <a class="thumbnail" href=
                                                "#"><img alt="50x50" data-src=
                                                "holder.js/50x50" src=
                                                "images/thumbnails/theodorecaldwell-75x75.jpg"
                                                style=
                                                "width: 50px; height: 50px;"></a>
                                            </li>

                                    </div>

                                    <div class="staff-image">

                                            <li>
                                                <a class="thumbnail" href=
                                                "#"><img alt="50x50" data-src=
                                                "holder.js/50x50" src=
                                                "images/thumbnails/kylefoster-75x75.jpg"
                                                style=
                                                "width: 50px; height: 50px;"></a>
                                            </li>

                                    </div>

                                    <div class="staff-image">

                                            <li>
                                                <a class="thumbnail" href=
                                                "#"><img alt="50x50" data-src=
                                                "holder.js/50x50" src=
                                                "images/thumbnails/tonishalane-75x75.jpg"
                                                style=
                                                "width: 50px; height: 50px;"></a>
                                            </li>

                                    </div>

                                    <div class="staff-image">

                                            <li>
                                                <a class="thumbnail" href=
                                                "#"><img alt="50x50" data-src=
                                                "holder.js/50x50" src=
                                                "images/thumbnails/maggieramsey-75x75.jpg"
                                                style=
                                                "width: 50px; height: 50px;" /></a>
                                            </li>

                                    </div>

                                    <div class="staff-image">

                                            <li>
                                                <a class="thumbnail" href=
                                                "#"><img alt="50x50" data-src=
                                                "holder.js/50x50" src=
                                                "images/thumbnails/rickeycaldwell-75x75.jpg"
                                                style=
                                                "width: 50px; height: 50px;"></a>
                                            </li>

                                    </div>

                                    <div class="staff-image">

                                            <li>
                                                <a class="thumbnail" href=
                                                "#"><img alt="50x50" data-src=
                                                "holder.js/50x50" src=
                                                "images/thumbnails/placeholder-75x75.jpg"
                                                style=
                                                "width: 50px; height: 50px;" /></a>
                                            </li>

                                    </div>
                                    </ol>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--=================end Thumbnails==============-->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--======================= News ========================-->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <div id="news">


                            <h2>News and Announcements</h2>
                        </div>

                        <div class="media">
                            <a class="pull-left" href="#"><img alt="64x64"
                            class="media-object" data-src="holder.js/64x64"
                            src="images/thumbnails/news%20placeholder.jpg"
                            style="width: 100px; height: 80px;" /></a>

                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>

                                <div class="media-news">
                                    Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida
                                    nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque.
                                </div><a class="btn-news" href="#">Read
                                More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="media">
                            <a class="pull-left" href="#"><img alt="64x64"
                            class="media-object" data-src="holder.js/64x64"
                            src="images/thumbnails/news%20placeholder.jpg"
                            style="width: 100px; height: 80px;" /></a>

                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>

                                <div class="media-news">
                                    Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida
                                    nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque.
                                </div><a class="btn-news" href="#">Read
                                More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="media">
                            <a class="pull-left" href="#"><img alt="64x64"
                            class="media-object" data-src="holder.js/64x64"
                            src="images/thumbnails/news%20placeholder.jpg"
                            style="width: 100px; height: 80px;" /></a>

                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>

                                <div class="media-news">
                                    Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida
                                    nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque.
                                </div><a class="btn-news" href="#">Read
                                More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--================End News Items==================-->
                    </div>
                    <!--======================= Events ======================-->

                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div id="events">


                            <h2>Events</h2>
                        </div>

                        <div class="media">
                            <a class="pull-left" href="#"><img alt="64x64"
                            class="media-object" data-src="holder.js/64x64"
                            src="images/thumbnails/news%20placeholder.jpg"
                            style="width: 70px; height: 50px;" /></a>

                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>

                                <div class="media-news">
                                    Date Time
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="media">
                            <a class="pull-left" href="#"><img alt="64x64"
                            class="media-object" data-src="holder.js/64x64"
                            src="images/thumbnails/news%20placeholder.jpg"
                            style="width: 70px; height: 50px;" /></a>

                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>

                                <div class="media-news">
                                    Date Time
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="media">
                            <a class="pull-left" href="#"><img alt="64x64"
                            class="media-object" data-src="holder.js/64x64"
                            src="images/thumbnails/news%20placeholder.jpg"
                            style="width: 70px; height: 50px;" /></a>

                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>

                                <div class="media-news">
                                    Date Time
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="media">
                            <a class="pull-left" href="#"><img alt="64x64"
                            class="media-object" data-src="holder.js/64x64"
                            src="images/thumbnails/news%20placeholder.jpg"
                            style="width: 70px; height: 50px;"></a>

                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>

                                <div class="media-news">
                                    Date Time
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--==================== Highlights =====================-->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <div id="highlights">


                            <h2>Highlights</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--======================= Showcase ====================-->

                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div id="showcase">


                            <h2>Showcase</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!--end content -->
            <!--======================= Footer ====================-->

            <div class="footer">
                <!-- copyrights region -->
                <div class="container">
                <div class="copyrights-wrapper" id="copyrights-wrapper">
                    <div id="footer-msu-logo">
                        <a href="http://www.msu.edu">Michigan State
                        University</a>
                    </div><!-- footer-msu-logo -->

                    <div id="footer-copyrights">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div><!--end #footer -->
        </div>


 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 600px; 
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    position: relative; //make #wrapper position non-static
    min-height: 99%;
}





/*body {background-color:#000;}*/ 

h2 {
    padding: 10px;

    font:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color:#FFF}

.container 
{
    background-color:#FFF;
    padding-bottom: 5px;



}



.headerwrapper{
    background-color:#000;
    width:100%;
    border:inset;
    border-color:#FFF;


}


ul.thumbnails li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.staff-image {
    margin: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type:none;
}


.staff {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}


.nav a{
    color:#FFF;
    padding: 5px;
}

.nav {
    width:100%;
    background-color: #000;
    border:solid;
    border-color:#FFF;



}

.news-body {
}

.media {
    margin-left: 13px;
}

.media-heading {

    color: #03F;
}

.media-news {

    font-size: 12px;

}

.media {
    padding-bottom: 5px;

    border-bottom: solid;
    border-bottom-width: thin;
    border-color: #CCC;
}


#about {
    margin-top:5px;
    background-color:#000;

    }


#staff {
    margin-top:5px;
    background-color:#000;
}


#news {
    margin-top:5px;
    background-color:#000;
}

#events {
    margin-top: 5px;
    background-color:#000;
}

#highlights {
    margin-top:5px;
    background-color:#000;
}

#showcase {
    margin-top:5px;
    background-color:#000;
}


.dpo-about {
    margin-left: 13px;
}

.btn-news {
    background-image: 0 0 60%;
    background-image: 0 0 60%;
    background-image: 0 0 60%;
    background-image: 0 0 60%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(top,rgba(230,230,230,1) 0 60%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,1);
    border: solid 1px rgba(102,102,102,1);
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 65px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 13px;
    text-indent: -2px;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgba(120,120,120,1);
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-left: 210px;
}

.btn-news:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.btn-news:active {
}

/* Footer */

.footer{
    height: 50px; 
    background-color: #174137;
    text-align: center;
}

.copyrights-wrapper {
    background-color:#174137;

}
```

Comment: Add one more `</div>` and it will be OUTSIDE the footer, as it stands it's nested inside the container.

Comment: To avoid getting lost in Div's maybe use some HTML5 elements to break up the page more clearly in your example you could use header, nav, section and footer and don't forget <!DOCTYPE html> in the header and for older IE add the html5shiv.js polyfill.

Comment: also you could use pseudo-code for the non-relevant parts xD

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone.  The answer below was able to fix my issue. Yea I guess I could've used pseudo-code.  I just wasn't sure where my issue was.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an invalid CSS comment (*using `//` instead of `/* */`*)

```
//make #wrapper position non-static min-height: 99%;
```

should be

```
/*make #wrapper position non-static min-height: 99%;*/
```

And more important is the missing `)` at the end of the `linear-gradient`

```
background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(230, 230, 230, 1) 0 60%;
```

This causes all the following CSS to be assumed to belong to the `linear-gradient` rule..

So just do it

```
background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(230, 230, 230, 1) 0 60%);
```

and it will work. ..

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/Gy43Q/

Comment: This worked for the footer.  Thanks a bunch.  I never knew about this gradient issue.